# Using 'sed' on a JSON file to find and replace

Tags: json, regex, unix, sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace >\u00018øÏùÄ with null in a json file that was converted incorrectly by another group. But sed doesn't seem to do anything

```
sed -i 's|B\u001eøøïùÄ|null|g' 02_20060711_002_2.json
```

For example if the json looks like

```
{"my_log (PA1)": {"test_number_n": "3999999", "timestamp_log": "04:28:21.218", "trans_blah_i": "0", "record_test_type": {"sequence_nbr_u": "999"}, "filler_2_s": "", "dd": {"ty": {"ex_user_code": {"country_id_s": "", "user_id_s": "", "filed2": ""}, "whose": {"testing_code": {"city_id_s": "", "user_id_s": "", "fggstomer_s": ""}, "ex_client_s": "", "filler_2_s": ""}, "series": {"ticket_c": "0", "strike_test_i": "0", "can_n": "0", "country_c": "0", "instrument_group_c": "0", "expiration_date_n": "0", "modifier_c": "0"}, "exchange_info_s": "", "customer_info_s": "B\u001eøøïùÄ", "onu": "34", "ak": "0", "trading_code": {"city_id_s": "jk", "user_id_s": "O05", "ex_cur_s": "21  "}}, "timestamp_in_q": "03:28:21.217"}}}
```

Comment: So writing a java app to parse the document? We have 10TBs of these docs.

Comment: Also I should mention that the reason I am trying to do this is because parsers seem to fall over when then read the json file DATA_READ ERROR: Error parsing JSON - Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xf8 File

Comment: Yeah I was using apache drill to query the file. Thanks thats helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash in your sed command.
Try this:

```
sed -i 's|B\\u001eøøïùÄ|null|g' 02_20060711_002_2.json
```

Tried it locally and it seemed to work.

Comment: Interestingly, If I run this on the file with one record in it, it works fine. If I run it against the entire file, it doesn't seem to do anything. Does sed have issues with large files?

Comment: Never mind its to do with the way the file is encoded.